# How to use SHA256 for MGF1ParameterSpec WCF service(.NET) with configuration

Tags: .net, wcf, configuration

need help to set SHA256 for session/transit key in WCF server.

```
<e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="_0">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
<DigestMethod xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
```

How to get "`xmlenc#sha256`" DigestMethod for EncryptedKey.

I have existing service which show SHA1 need to upgrade with SHA256. Have try multiple option but SHA1 is not getting change with SHA256 for EncryptedKey. In java some one has done this but i need to implement the same in .NET WCF with configuration.

Comment: Specifying a Custom Crypto Algorithm: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/specifying-a-custom-crypto-algorithm?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I didn't found any this to modify algorithm to sha256 rsa-oaep-mgf1p.